# Prettyfaces custom URL is not hitting

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I am using pretty faces with jsf 2.0 but it is not showing output when hitting the url. I added the prettyfaces-core-3.3.2.jar. Here is the configurations i have made.

home.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>
Hello Pretty Faces
</h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <display-name>Pretty</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class
</listener>
</web-app>
```

pretty-config.xml

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                  http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

<url-mapping id="home">
    <pattern value="/home" />
    <view-id value="/faces/home.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
</pretty-config>
```

This is the configurations I have done but it is not working. Can someone tell me the mistake I made in the configurations. Thnaks in advance.

Comment: The PrettyFaces version you are using is VERY OLD. You should really update before trying anything else.

Comment: As Chkal said. Try upgrading to the most recent version. You can find information here on the project website: http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/